# null pointer exception while resizing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, null

I have a `NullPointerException` in the line "`newIndexer[i].index = (int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`" and I cannot figure out why. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    public void resizeIndexer(int newKey)
    {   
        if (maxHeap >= newKey)
            return;
        if (newKey > maxHeap){
            Handle[] newIndexer = new Handle[newKey + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < newKey; i++){
                if (i < maxHeap)
                newIndexer[i] = this.Indexer[i];
                else{
                    System.out.println(i);
                    newIndexer[i].index = (int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                    newIndexer[i].status = false;
                }
            }       
            maxHeap = newKey;
            Indexer = newIndexer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, check why you exceed the length of your array. Also, I don't this is the best way to go: `(int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is designed to work with `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new Handle instance for each new index of the new array before modifying the `index` and `status` members :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < newKey; i++){
            if (i < maxHeap)
                newIndexer[i] = this.Indexer[i];
            else{
                System.out.println(i);
                newIndexer[i] = new Handle ();
                newIndexer[i].index = (int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                newIndexer[i].status = false;
            }
        }
```